# arrange tracks by index number using Applescript

Tags: indexing, applescript

Can someone give me an example of how do we sort the playlist in iTunes by their index number using **Applescript**

Basically I want to add the tracks at the bottom of the playlist, so if there is a way that before adding if I can lock the playlist based on the track number (index number) so that i can add the track directly and it goes at the bottom of the playlist directly.

Answer (score 0):

The displayed sort order doesn't affect the position of a track in a playlist. Tracks are always added to the end. Simply use the `duplicate` command to add a track to the playlist.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    duplicate (track "Ride of the Valkyries" of library playlist 1) to playlist "Go Fast"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the added track **1st track of playlist**, the playlist should be recreated this way:

```
tell application "Music"
    
    tell playlist "playlist 2"
        set tracksIDs to database ID of tracks -- remember IDs before deleting
        delete tracks -- delete
    end tell
    
    duplicate track "AC-DC - T.N.T." of library playlist 1 to playlist "playlist 2" -- add the track you need
    
    -- add the deleted tracks back
    repeat with trackID in tracksIDs
        duplicate (every track of library playlist 1 whose database ID is trackID) to playlist "playlist 2"
    end repeat
    
end tell
```